# Is this equivalence relation correct?

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces, equivalence-relations

The norms $\def\n#1{\lVert\,\rVert_{#1}} \n1$ and $\n2$ are said equivalent, if and only if, there are real numbers, $\alpha > 0, \beta > 0$ such that $\alpha \n1 \leq \n2 \leq \beta \n1$.

Consider the relation $\n1 \sim \n2$ if and only if $\n1$ and $\n2$ are equivalent, check that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

Solución:
where $\alpha, \beta > 0$ if:

$\alpha \n1 \leq \n2$ then $\n1 \leq \frac{1}{\alpha} \n2$

$\n2 \leq \beta \n1$ then $\frac{1}{\beta} \n2 \leq \n1$

For the transitive, if:

$\alpha\, \n1 \leq \n2 \leq \beta\, \n1$

$\alpha' \n2 \leq \n3 \leq \beta' \n2$

Then:

$\alpha\alpha'\n1 \leq \n3 \leq \beta\beta'\n1$

this right? If not, I appreciate you can help me with a better way to write it.

Comment: Looks right for me. But it's necessary to check that it is reflexive

Comment: how is it checked? can you help me check it please?

Comment: Why $\mid\mid\cdot\mid\mid\sim\mid\mid\cdot\mid\mid$ for all $\mid\mid\cdot\mid\mid$?

Comment: I don't understand Martin

Comment: can you explain me step by step? I'm studying for my test

Comment: You have to show reflexivity and symmetry as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have all the important parts of the argument for the symmetric and transitive properties. But it would be nice to show conclusions explicitly in each case. Since the relation is defined by the existence of these positive real scalars, it's nice to explicitly name the scalars in the conclusion.

For instance, for symmetric property:
$$
\lVert\,\rVert_1 \sim \lVert\,\rVert_2 
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\alpha \lVert\,\rVert_1 
\leq \lVert\,\rVert_2 
\leq \beta \lVert\,\rVert_1
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\tfrac{1}{\beta} \lVert\,\rVert_2 
\leq \lVert\,\rVert_1 
\leq \tfrac{1}{\alpha} \lVert\,\rVert_2
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\lVert\,\rVert_2 \sim \lVert\,\rVert_1 
$$

For the transitive property:
$$
\left.
\begin{aligned}
\lVert\,\rVert_1 \sim \lVert\,\rVert_2 
\;&\Rightarrow\;
\,\alpha\, \lVert\,\rVert_1 
\leq \lVert\,\rVert_2 
\leq \beta\, \lVert\,\rVert_1 \\
\lVert\,\rVert_2 \sim \lVert\,\rVert_3 
\;&\Rightarrow\;
\alpha' \lVert\,\rVert_2 
\leq \lVert\,\rVert_3 
\leq \beta' \lVert\,\rVert_2
\end{aligned}
\;\right\}\!\!\!\Rightarrow \;
\alpha^{}\alpha' \lVert\,\rVert_1 
\leq \lVert\,\rVert_3 
\leq \beta^{}\beta' \lVert\,\rVert_1 
\;\Rightarrow\; 
\lVert\,\rVert_1 \sim \lVert\,\rVert_3 
$$

For the reflexive property, just note that both scalars can be $1$:
$$
1\, \lVert\,\rVert_1 
\leq \lVert\,\rVert_1 
\leq 1\, \lVert\,\rVert_1
\quad\Rightarrow\quad 
\lVert\,\rVert_1 \sim \lVert\,\rVert_1 
$$

Comment: martîn, what is the correct way to solve this exercise? Can you explain it to me step by step? also what of the reflective property? I need help please.

Comment: I can edit to include more details.

Comment: please, I appreciate your help. I got stuck in that problem and I have not been able to move forward. I need the step-by-step explanation of this exercise, I don't want to fail my exam